# In simple terms, how do ext4 journaling file systems work?

Tags: windows, filesystem, ext4, ext3

How does a journaling file system work and why does it not fragment, like NTFS?

Why hasn't Windows switched over to a journaling file system?

Could someone please explain this to me? Thanks.

Comment: How simple? "*Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.*" **- Larry Niven**

Comment: Well, not so simple so that I'm missing out on stuff, but simple enough for someone who wants to just touch on the topic to get an answer.

Comment: NTFS *is* a journalling filesystem, see Wikipedia for instance.

Comment: The second question (why Windows hasn't switched over) can't possibly be answered here on the Ask Ubuntu site. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from PC World [Ubuntu Linux, Day 16: EXT4 vs. NTFS](https://www.pcworld.com/article/485470/ubuntu_linux_day_16_ext4_vs_ntfs.html):

> EXT4 can support individual files up to 16 terabytes, and volumes up
> to one exabyte in size. But, one of the aspects of EXT4 which
> contributes to better performance, though, is that EXT4 can handle
> larger extents-a range of contiguous physical blocks of data. This
> allows it to work better with large files and reduce drive
> fragmentation.
>
> Other factors include the allocate-on-flush technique used by EXT4. By
> delaying allocation of data blocks until the data is ready to be
> written to disk, EXT4 improves performance and reduces fragmentation
> compared to file systems that allocate blocks earlier.
>
> Using checksums for drive journaling improves reliability and improves
> performance by avoiding waiting on the disk during the journaling
> process. When it comes to file checking, EXT4 is quicker because
> unallocated blocks of data are marked as such and are simply skipped
> during disk check operations.

Any discussion around 'why/why not' and 'defrag' needs to include Diskeeper (formerly Executive Software). Offering to license your product to Redmond, and having your company and/or product still be viable in two years, is a Herculean adventure at best ..

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Your'e going to need more then 30 days to see if ext4 makes a difference, though. How large of a file size can ntfs support? 16 terabytes is an awful lot of data.

Comment: The was their '30 days', and you should direct such comments  to them ..

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to give an extended but simple answer, based on available sources:

Simple definition of a journaling file system from [PC World](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/journaling-file-system):

> A file system that contains its own recovery capability in the event
> of a failure. In a journaling file system, the information about the
> changes is recorded in a separate log (the journal) before the indexes
> to the files are updated. If a power or other system failure corrupts
> the indexes as they are being rewritten, the operating system can use
> the log to repair them when the computer is restarted.

A little more detail from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system):

> Updating file systems to reflect changes to files and directories
> usually requires many separate write operations. This makes it
> possible for an interruption (like a power failure or system crash)
> between writes to leave data structures in an invalid intermediate
> state.
>
> For example, deleting a file on a Unix file system involves three
> steps:
>
> 1. Removing its directory entry.
> 2. Releasing the inode to the pool of free inodes.
> 3. Returning all disk blocks to the pool of free disk blocks.
>
> If a crash occurs after step 1 and before step 2, there will be an
> orphaned inode and hence a storage leak; if a crash occurs between
> steps 2 and 3, then the blocks previously used by the file cannot be
> used for new files, effectively decreasing the storage capacity of the
> file system. Re-arranging the steps does not help, either. (...)
>
> (...)
>
> To prevent this, a journaled file system allocates a special area—the
> journal—in which it records the changes it will make ahead of time.
> After a crash, recovery simply involves reading the journal from the
> file system and replaying changes from this journal until the file
> system is consistent again. (...)

In addition, `ext4` uses some other techniques to reduce fragmentation, namely *Extends* and *Delayed allocation* (again from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4)):

> ###### Extents
>
> Extents replace the traditional block mapping scheme used by
> ext2 and ext3. An extent is a range of contiguous physical blocks,
> improving large-file performance and reducing fragmentation. A single
> extent in ext4 can map up to 128 MiB of contiguous space with a 4 KiB
> block size. There can be four extents stored directly in the inode.
> When there are more than four extents to a file, the rest of the
> extents are indexed in a tree.
>
> ###### Delayed allocation
>
> ext4 uses a performance technique called
> allocate-on-flush, also known as delayed allocation. That is, ext4
> delays block allocation until data is flushed to disk; in contrast,
> some file systems allocate blocks immediately, even when the data goes
> into a write cache. Delayed allocation improves performance and
> reduces fragmentation by effectively allocating larger amounts of data
> at a time.

I hope this gives the very basic of the operations of journaling filesystems, and specifically some `ext4` details.